# About wsimport vs wsld2java for SOAP request client

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, wsdl2java, wsimport

I've just generated the java source files to build a Web Service client, using the wsimport of jdk1.7.

```
wsimport -keep /path/to/wsdl
```

For make the SOAP request I used the clasess under generated folder. Everything went ok, with a response 200 :)

But then, I wanted to use (for ... 'fun') CXF (v.2.7) wsdl2java tool to make exactly the same, but using this tool it doesn't generate the classes needed for the SOAP Request, it doesn't create the generated folder either.

```
wsdl2java -keep -verbose /path/to/wsdl
```

Also I notice that the class ObjectFactory that the tools create by its own, are different. Using wsdl2java creates a much short file.

So, why are those tools generating different results ??

I dont clearly understand the difference about this two, can u help me ??

The wsdl used is importing xsd files, that have a well-know problem, which I've resolved thanks to this blog entry 
[here](http://sprinkl.be/2012/05/29/about-cxf-and-problems-with-imports-and-jaxb/)

Thanks for your answer